# MenuItem Click event only fired once when modifying it's own ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, binding, command, menuitem

I'm trying to understand why the Click event on the MenuItem is fired **only once** if you add an item to the ItemsSource.

But if you add items through another control (i.e a button) then the Click event keeps firing?

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem" Click="MenuItem_Click" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Height="100" Width="100">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MyViewModel)DataContext).AddNewItem(null);
        }
}
```

```
public class MyViewModel
{
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MyViewModel() { }

        public void AddNewItem(object x)
        {
            MyItems.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Click` event of the `MenuItem` is captured when there are child items to display.

If you click on an added `MenuItem` that has no children, your event handler will be invoked again.

You could handle another event like for example `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to overcome this "issue".